# If people in Iron Age times had access to uranium, would it be used over iron?

Tags: warfare, medieval, alternate-history, chemistry, metalworking

Let's say that in 1,200 BC, aliens secretly come to Earth and turn all of the uranium oxides into pure uranium.The aliens then leave and humans discover this new metal.

Uranium has a lower melting point than iron so forges could use it easily. If antiquity blacksmiths had access to uranium and uranium alloys, would they use uranium in weapons, armor, and other metal tools? Or would the Iron Age blacksmiths just stick to iron anyway?

Comment: We're talking about the radioactive metal, uranium, right? The one that starts nasty chain reactions and is currently melting it's way to the Earth's core under Chernobyl? The one who's most common isotope breaks down into plutonium? The one that's almost as heavy as gold?

Comment: -1 for lack of basic research. Pure uranium is [naturally radioactive](https://www.livescience.com/39773-facts-about-uranium.html), killing everyone who works with it and causing birth defects in the children of all who spawn before dying. adding carbon to uranium doesn't harden it like it does iron (post iron-age, yes), it creates uranium carbide, [a nuclear fuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium_carbide). Depleted uranium could work as a replacement for steel (yup, not iron, I get it) - if it didn't take a nuclear reactor to create it and if it weren't radioactive.

Comment: Depleted uranium is ‘created’ by taking much of the U-235 out. Nuclear reactors have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JonCuster Well that's just embarrassing to whine and complain about a failure to do basic research and confuse the enrichment process with reactor byproducts. I appreciate you pointing it out. Thanks!

Comment: Does affecting their culture and mythology count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Bad Idea:

There are a number of bad qualities to Uranium. Let's skip the radiation part.

- **Heavy**: Uranium is just slightly less dense than gold, making it extremely heavy.
- **Oxidation**: Uranium oxidizes easily. For technological applications, this isn't too big a deal, but in medieval worlds, it's not great. Once is does oxidize, uranium oxide is toxic. Uranium miners suffer high rates of cancer.
- [**Pyrophoric**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrophoricity): Uranium can spontaneously ignite exposed to air or high temperatures. Useful if you can prevent it from being exposed to the air - or water - or if you want a shell that can ignite after hitting a tank. Not so good when you're wearing it.
- **Impure**: Uranium tends to contain high levels of other radioactive and toxic heavy metals like radium and polonium.
- **Radon**: Decaying uranium releases radon, a radioactive gas known to cause lung cancer.

But it's not all bad news.

- [Ferrouranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrouranium): This alloy of iron and uranium can be used to make hardened steels and lowering the melting point of iron. It's likely these alloys would become more frequent in your world. Ferrouranium was used for tool making during WW1 and just after, but other materials ended up being more viable long-term.
- Nickel-uranium alloys are highly chemical-resistant, even against highly aggressive compounds like aqua regia.

Answer (score 2):

In a world where all available uranium oxide was converted to pure uranium, given the availability of iron compared to uranium, you wouldn't see wide use of uranium.

Iron makes up roughly 5% of the Earth's crust. That makes it the 4th most abundant element in the crust. By comparison there are is an average 2.8 parts per million of Uranium in the crust. Even if we assume that every uranium atom is uranium trioxide and that every oxygen atom is converted to uranium you'd only have 11.2 parts per million of uranium to 50,000 parts per million iron.

Uranium is a poor choice for forging. It oxides readily. It isn't an accident that uranium is almost always found as an oxide. Any attempt to heat or melt it will result in oxide production. The reactivity of Uranium and Oxygen is so strong that small chips will spontaneously combust when exposed to air. This means that even cold working, or filing, will promote oxide formation.

Comment: For the purpose of the hypothetical, let's say that the aliens make the pure uranium resistant against forming uranium oxide again after they change it.

Comment: @ITM_Coder That's not the question you asked. Please remember we're not a discussion site.

Comment: @ITM_Coder Uranium is really oxidative. That's why even reactors tend to use the oxides, not the metals. There are a few tricks to slightly modify the oxidation (slightly), but otherwise you'd need to fundamentally change the nature of the element to keep it from oxidizing. It's a big part of why they use depleted uranium shells instead of something like tungsten. Sorry. On the plus, it's more abundant than silver, and people made a wide use of silver despite it's relative rarity.

Comment: Would the instantaneous liberation of all the oxygen create any issues in the atmosphere?

Comment: @elemtilas There shouldn't be any oxygen liberation issues since the uranium was converted to pure uranium, via <handwaves>, thermodynamics be damned. Given that OP is asking follow up questions where the chemical properties of uranium are modified without specifying a process, we can assume that the pre-conditions to the Q can be assumed to just happen, thermodynamics be damned.

Comment: Well, if they convert all the Uox to U, that leaves some oxygen left over! Since you seem to be addressing the numbers, I figured you might have some idea if the oxygen liberated would have any non-negligible effect on the atmosphere.

Comment: @elemtilas If the 3 oxygen in UO3 are converted to Uranium. There is no liberated oxygen, U4. Note how I said that this was an **handwaved** process. OP literally says that aliens did it. It's just fluff in the OP's question, about Uranium's use as an alternative to iron. Which has nothing to do with side effects of the unspecified mechanism for transforming Uranium Oxide into pure uranium in situ.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly as bullets or crossbow bolts or some such. After all, the military does use depleted Uranium as bullets. This would be useful in a situation where the high density was an advantage. In some circumstances, the pyrophoric nature of Uranium would make such bullets pretty effective.

Uranium metal is [harder than ordinary steel.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness) Ordinary steel has a Mohs hardness of about 4.5, and Uranium comes in at 6. It means that you can put quite a tip on a bullet.

Since guns existed in Europe in the [13th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun#Transition_to_true_guns) Uranium might have found use as ammunition.

It is conceivable that [Uranium might be used in armor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chobham_armour#Heavy_metal_modules) Although it is a challenge for medieval technology to make an alloy that will be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

### No, due to chemical toxicity

Aside from all the problems with radioactivity, uranium is one of the most toxic non radioactive elements. It's both an acute and a chronic poison, and a powerful carcinogen. This is the problem with depleted uranium; it's not radioactive, despite opponents claims - but it's poisonous and carcinogenic anyway.

Its volatile oxides mean that, like arsenic, you can't smelt it safely. In the Bronze Age, they made bronze with arsenic before they swapped it out for tin; it appears entire villages were abandoned due to accumulated arsenic toxicity from its oxide. A medieval village messing with uranium can expect the same fate.